# TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable in function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

please help me. I have this code,

```
def detect_outliers(df, x):
    Q1 = df[x].quantile['25%']
    Q3 = df[x].quantile['75%']
    IQR = Q3-Q1
    return df[(df[x] < Q1-1.5*IQR) | (df[x] > Q3+1.5*IQR)]

detect_outliers(df, 'SepalWidthCm')
```

Output :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-8e2965ea440c> in <module>()
----> 1 detect_outliers(df, 'SepalWidthCm')

<ipython-input-7-74f01c91dd66> in detect_outliers(df, x)
      1 def detect_outliers(df, x):
----> 2     Q1 = df[x].quantile['25%']
      3     Q3 = df[x].quantile['75%']
      4     IQR = Q3-Q1
      5     return df[(df[x] < Q1-1.5*IQR) | (df[x] > Q3+1.5*IQR)]

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

So, what's wrong with this code. Please help me.Thank you

Comment: `quantile()` is a function, try `df[x].quantile(q=.25)`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)